# What is the difference between the | and || or operators?

Tags: c#, php, operators

I have always used `||` (two pipes) in OR expressions, both in C# and PHP. Occasionally I see a single pipe used: `|`. What is the difference between those two usages? Are there any caveats when using one over the other or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 581, accepted):

Just like the `&` and `&&` operator, the double Operator is a "short-circuit" operator.

For example:

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3)
```

If condition1 is true, condition 2 and 3 will NOT be checked.

```
if(condition1 | condition2 | condition3)
```

This will check conditions 2 and 3, even if 1 is already true. As your conditions can be quite expensive functions, you can get a good performance boost by using them.

There is one big caveat, NullReferences or similar problems. For example:

```
if(class != null && class.someVar < 20)
```

If class is null, the if-statement will stop after `class != null` is false. If you only use &, it will try to check `class.someVar` and you get a nice `NullReferenceException`. With the Or-Operator that may not be that much of a trap as it's unlikely that you trigger something bad, but it's something to keep in mind.

No one ever uses the single `&` or `|` operators though, unless you have a design where each condition is a function that HAS to be executed. Sounds like a design smell, but sometimes (rarely) it's a clean way to do stuff. The `&` operator does "run these 3 functions, and if one of them returns false, execute the else block", while the `|` does "only run the else block if none return false" - can be useful, but as said, often it's a design smell.

There is a Second use of the `|` and `&` operator though: [Bitwise Operations](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chandrahundigam/BitWiserOpsInCS11082005050940AM/BitWiserOpsInCS.aspx).

Comment: and `or` is not short-circuiting?

Answer (score 91):

|| is the logical OR operator. It sounds like you basically know what that is. It's used in conditional statements such as if, while, etc.

```
condition1 || condition2
```

Evaluates to true if either condition1 OR condition2 is true.

| is the bitwise OR operator. It's used to operate on two numbers. You look at each bit of each number individually and, if one of the bits is 1 in at least one of the numbers, then the resulting bit will be 1 also. Here are a few examples:

```
A = 01010101
B = 10101010
A | B = 11111111

A = 00000001
B = 00010000
A | B = 00010001

A = 10001011
B = 00101100

A | B = 10101111
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

So to answer the last two questions, I wouldn't say there are any caveats besides "know the difference between the two operators." They're not interchangeable because they do two completely different things.

Comment: This helped me understand how someone was using bitwise OR operator to merge filters in Mongodb C# driver. https://gist.github.com/a3dho3yn/91dcc7e6f606eaefaf045fc193d3dcc3#combine-filters

Comment: *"It's used to operate on two numbers"* This is an inaccurate/incomplete description. `if (true | false)` is perfectly valid in C#.

Comment: @arkon, If you go bitwise, 1 is true and 0 is false. So, these booleans might actually be taken as zero and ones. You can't do "str1" | "str2" can you?

Answer (score 36):

One is a "bitwise or".

> 10011b | 01000b => 11011b

The other is a logic or.

> true or false => true

Comment: `|` can be used on `bool` types as well without short circuiting.

Comment: For anyone not familiar with bitwise operators, the result example is obtained because each bit row from each column is tested against the other using OR comparison. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 21):

Good question.  These two operators work the same in PHP and C#.

`|` is a bitwise OR.  It will compare two values by their bits.  E.g. 1101 | 0010 = 1111.  This is extremely useful when using bit options.  E.g. Read = 01 (0X01) Write = 10 (0X02)  Read-Write = 11 (0X03).  One useful example would be opening files.  A simple example would be:

```
File.Open(FileAccess.Read | FileAccess.Write);  //Gives read/write access to the file
```

`||` is a logical OR.  This is the way most people think of OR and compares two values based on their truth.  E.g. I am going to the store or I will go to the mall.  This is the one used most often in code. For example:

```
if(Name == "Admin" || Name == "Developer") { //allow access } //checks if name equals Admin OR Name equals Developer
```

PHP Resource: https://www.php.net/language.operators.bitwise

C# Resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(VS.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(VS.71).aspx

Comment: FWIW, Technically, in C# `|` is a **logical or** when applied to **booleans**. As your linked reference states. In practice, the end result is the same as if it were a bitwise operator, because the bitwise values of `true` and `false` are such that a bitwise or of their values produces the exact same result as a logical or does. That is `(int)(bool1 | bool2)` == `((int)bool1) | ((int)bool2)`.

Answer (score 19):

& - (Condition 1 & Condition 2): checks both cases even if first one is false

&& - (Condition 1 && Condition 2): dosen't bother to check second case if case one 
                                   is false

&& - operator will make your code run faster, professionally & is rarely used

| - (Condition 1 | Condition 2): checks both cases even if case 1 is true

|| - (Condition 1 || Condition 2): dosen't  bother to check second case if first 
                                   one is true

|| - operator will make your code run faster, professionally | is rarely used

Comment: `rarely used`? All depends on what you want or need to do.

Comment: Great! Short and sweet, I would remove the "| is rarely used" and "& is rarely used" because, as Emaborsa said, its really depends on what you want or need to do.

Comment: I rely on bitwise operations quite heavily. These specific operators are also useful when dealing with flags. You're mistaking *people rarely use them* with *I rarely use them*.

Comment: *Is rarely used* means *is rarely the appropriate operator,* because in all possible cases an "or" operation should short-circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Simple example in java

```
public class Driver {

  static int x;
  static int y;

public static void main(String[] args) 
throws Exception {

System.out.println("using double pipe");
    if(setX() || setY())
        {System.out.println("x = "+x);
        System.out.println("y = "+y);
        }



System.out.println("using single pipe");
if(setX() | setY())
    {System.out.println("x = "+x);
    System.out.println("y = "+y);
    }

}

 static boolean setX(){
      x=5;
     return true;
  }
 static boolean setY(){
      y=5;
      return true;
  }
}
```

output :

```
using double pipe
x = 5
y = 0
using single pipe
x = 5
y = 5
```

Comment: Why would you give a java example for a question that doesn't even mention java?

Answer (score 0):

The single pipe, |, is one of the [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operators.

From Wikipedia:

> In the C programming language family, the bitwise OR operator is "|" (pipe). Again, this operator must not be confused with its Boolean "logical or" counterpart, which treats its operands as Boolean values, and is written "||" (two pipes).

Answer (score 0):

By their mathematical definition, OR and AND are binary operators; they verify the LHS and RHS conditions regardless, similarly to | and &.

|| and && alter the properties of the OR and AND operators by stopping them when the LHS condition isn't fulfilled.

Answer (score -1):

For bitwise `|` and Logicall `||`

OR

bitwise `&` and logicall `&&`

it means   `if( a>b | a==0)`
in this first left `a>b` will be evaluated and then `a==0` will be evaluated then `|` operation will be done

but in`|| if a>b` then if wont check for next RHS

Similarly for & and &&

`if(A>0 & B>0)`

it will evalue LHS and then RHS then do bitwise & but

in`(A>0 && B>0)`

`if(A>0)` is `false`(LHS) it will directly `return false;`

Answer (score -2):

The singe pipe "|" is the "bitwise" or and should only be used when you know what you're doing. The double pipe "||" is a logical or, and can be used in logical statements, like "x == 0 || x == 1".

Here's an example of what the bitwise or does: if a=0101 and b=0011, then a|b=0111. If you're dealing with a logic system that treats any non-zero as true, then the bitwise or will act in the same way as the logical or, but it's counterpart (bitwise and, "&") will NOT. Also the bitwise or does not perform short circuit evaluation.

Comment: '|' can also be used on `bool` types without short circuiting.

Answer (score -4):

The | operator performs a bitwise OR of its two operands (meaning both sides must evaluate to false for it to return false) while the || operator will only evaluate the second operator if it needs to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(VS.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(VS.71).aspx

Comment: If you actually read those articles, you would have seen that they are referring to bitwise operators

Comment: That's not what bitwise means.