# What is the difference between the | and || operators?

Tags: php, operators

`|` and `||` - what is the difference between these two operators in PHP?

Comment: [PHP Language Reference](http://us2.php.net/langref) : [Operators](http://us2.php.net/langref)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the diffference between the | and || or operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`|` is a [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) or, `||` is a [boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic) or.

Comment: Bitwise or means that the value of (a|b) is the set of bits that are set in either a or b.  Logical or means that the value of (a||b) is true if either a or b is true or both or true, false if neither is true.

Comment: As a smalll side question, in PHP can you use the bitwise or on booleans like you can in Java and C#? The practical difference in those cases is that the || will perform a shortcut where if the left disjunct returns true, the right is not checked, whereas with the single | it will perform the check in both cases.

Comment: @Jacob Bellamy : a simple test (`# php -r 'var_dump(true | true);'`) suggests that you can.  `bool(true)` is probably being automagically cast to `int(1)`.  I'd be a bit hesitant about using that syntax myself, as I wouldn't necessarily expect the other guys I work with to pick up on the subtle difference.  Similarly, I'm hesitant to use the `or` operator, which unlike `||`, is lower precedence than assignment.

Comment: Could you please help me.I'm doubtful about the use of ' | ' in the following context ( Laravel ). ['email' => 'required|email|unique:email,users']

Comment: That's a string. Read the Laravel docs to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 12):

#### Meaning

`|` is binary operator, it will binary OR the bits of both the lefthand and righthand values.

`||` is a boolean operator, it will [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) when it encounters 'true' (any non-zero value, this includes non-empty arrays).

#### Examples

```
print_r(1 | 2)  // 3
print_r(1 || 2) // 1
```

When used with functions:

```
function numberOf($val) {
    echo "$val, ";
    return $val;
}

echo numberOf(1) | numberOf(2);  // Will print 1, 2, 3
echo numberOf(1) || numberOf(2); // Will print 1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the & and && operator, the double Operator is a "short-circuit" operator.

For example:

if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3) 
If condition1 is true, condition 2 and 3 will NOT be checked.

if(condition1 | condition2 | condition3) 
This will check conditions 2 and 3, even if 1 is already true. As your conditions can be quite expensive functions, you can get a good

performance boost by using them.

There is one big caveat, NullReferences or similar problems. For example:

if(class != null && class.someVar < 20) 
If class is null, the if-statement will stop after "class != null" is false. If you only use &, it will try to check class.someVar and you get a

nice NullReferenceException. With the Or-Operator that may not be that much of a trap as it's unlikely that you trigger something bad,

but it's something to keep in mind.

No one ever uses the single & or | operators though, unless you have a design where each condition is a function that HAS the be

executed. Sounds like a design smell, but sometimes (rarely) it's a clean way to do stuff. The & operator does "run these 3 functions,

and if one of them returns false, execute the else block", while the | does "only run the else block if none return false" - can be useful,

but as said, often it's a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

| operates on the bits of a variable: 2 | 4 = 6

|| operates on The Boolean value of a variable: 2 || 4 = TRUE

Answer (score 0):

> | -> binary operator || -> Boolean operator or -> also a Boolean
> operator with lower precedence
>
> ```
> $x = false | true; //will set $x to an integer
> $x = false || true; //will set $x to true
> $x = false or true; //will set $x to false exactly the same that:
> ($x = false) || true;
> ```