# Php: What is the difference between | and || operator

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [What is the difference between the | and || operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233835/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators)

Just bumped into this line of code, and I was wondering what is the difference between these two case:

The person who did this do not remember what was the meaning, but it was important.

```
...
if ($condition1 | $condition2) {
...
```

```
...
if ($condition1 || $condition2) {
...
```

Comment: See [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233835/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: I tried to search for `operator` and `|` before asking the question, but didn't found anything (since I didn't know the term to use (bitwise operator). The question can be deleted, thanks.

Comment: @yvoyer: As a general tip, you can visit `php.net/whatever` and PHP will translate the whatever into a search for that term. The operators URL I posted above was the result of hitting `php.net/operator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR),  `||` is a logical or. `|` operates on binary values whereas `||` operates on boolean ones.

E.g. `5 | 3` is `0101 OR 0011` which is `0111` which is 7, whereas `True || False` is True and `False || False` is False.

Answer (score 2):

| = **bitwise** or

|| = **boolean** or

Answer (score 0):

`|` is the bitwise-OR-operator while `||` is the logical-OR-operator.