# What is the use of a single | in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the | and || operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233835/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I am starting to use PHP again and I always remember using single |'s a lot and all my books are in storage, so I cant use them for a refrence and google doesnt give me very much. Any help appreciated!

Comment: -1, what on earth did you google? I found the right manual page as the top result: www.google.co.nz/search?q=single+bar+or+operator+in+php

Answer (score 1):

bitwise OR http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Bitwise Inclusive OR
( 5 = 0101) = ( 0 = 0000) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 5 = 0101) = ( 1 = 0001) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 7 = 0111) = ( 2 = 0010) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 5 = 0101) = ( 4 = 0100) | ( 5 = 0101)
(13 = 1101) = ( 8 = 1000) | ( 5 = 0101)