# What is the difference between Bitwise AND & and LOGICAL AND &&

Tags: c#, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between logical and conditional AND, OR in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154132/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-and-conditional-and-or-in-c)

What is the difference between Bitwise AND & and Logical AND &&??

Comment: Did you think to look this up *anywhere*?

Comment: Nope Oli, there aren't any resources for that. Bitwise and logical operations only exist for a few days, you know?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=Bitwise+AND+%26+and+Logical+AND+%26%26&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @Femaref, I can't stop laughing...Good sense of humor

Comment: in some instances, sarcasm is the only valid solution.

Comment: sorry guys i did not realize it was duplicate. I am a beginner in developing and I never study IT at school... why did you vote down my question? It could make sense for a beginners like me have some explanation about basic concept?

Comment: because such information can be found on the net (or wikipedia for the matter) in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Ok Femaref I understand I Will be more careful next time. Anyway thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`&` modifies integers with bitwise operations, ie. `1000 & 1001 = 1000`, `&&` compares boolean values. However, `&` doubles as the non-shortcircuiting logical and, meaning if you have `false & true`, the second parameter would still be evaluated. This won't be the case with `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

Bitwise, as its name implies, it's an AND operation at the BIT level.

So, if you perform a BITWISE AND on two integers:

```
int a = 7;     // b00000111
int b = 3;     // b00000011
int c = a & b; // b00000011 (bitwise and)
```

On the other hand, in C#, logical AND operates at logical (boolean) level. So you need boolean values as operators, and result is another logical value:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;
bool c = a && b; // c is false
c = a && true; // c is true
```

But only at the logical level.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Good question (duplicated though).

**Bitwise AND** will affect its operators on the bit-level i.e. looping and doing logical AND operation on every bit.

On the other hand,

**Logical AND** will take 2 boolean operators to check their rightness (as a whole) and decide upon (notice that bool in C# is 2 bytes long).