# function gives wrong results

Tags: c++, algorithm, operators, combinations

I have tried writting the following function to generate all combinations of a string by translating the algorithm from my algorithm text. But it keeps print entire string in the output for all the combinations.

```
len = strlen(str);
for(i=0;i<pow(2,len);i++) 
{
        for(j=0;j<len;j++) 
        {
                if(i && (0x1 << j)) 
                {
                        cout<<str[j];
                }
        }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: Since this is C++, prefer to use `std::string` to `char *`.  Obtaining the length of a `std::string` is faster than scanning for `'\0'` in a `char *`. Also, `std::string` is safer and can grow.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: You do realize that `(len * len)` is not a substitute for `pow(2, len)`, right?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Sorry, my bad.  Got parameters mixed up.  Removed comment about `pow(2, len) == (len * len)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to check if the `j`th bit is set in variable `i` you need to use the bitwise `&` operator and not the logical `&&`:

```
if(i && (0x1 << j))
     ^^
```

Comment: You'll find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051349/what-is-the-difference-bettween-bitwise-and-and-logical-and