# Use of Bitwise AND (&) in this scenario

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen some explanations of `&` (and plenty of explanations of `|`) around SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051349/what-is-the-difference-bettween-bitwise-and-and-logical-and) etc), but none which  clarify the use of the `&` in the following scenario:

```
else if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)  {...}
```

Taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.allowedeffect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can anyone explain this, specific to this usage?

Thanks.

Comment: It checks if `DragDropEffects.Move` is one of the set flags in the `AllowedEffect` enum value. [This should be useful reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Comment: Note that the example is a little old. There is `e.AllowedEffect.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move)` from .NET 4. You may find that easier to understand.

Comment: @JesseGood A better choice is most circumstances. But it has downsides: 1) It's slower 2) It's not obvious what will happen if you specify multiple flags. (It checks if all flags are set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.AllowedEffect` is possibly a combination of bitwise flags. The `&` operator performs a bit a bit "and" logical operation with each bit. As a result if the bit under test is one, the result is that single flag.
The test could be writter in this way with exactly the same result:

```
else if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Move) != 0 )  {...}
```

Lets explain better with an example, the flag value are these:

```
None = 0,

    Copy = 1,

    Move = 2,

    Link = 4,
```

So in binary:

None = 00000000,

```
Copy = 00000001,

Move = 00000010,

Link = 00000100,
```

So we consider the case in which under test we have the combination of Copy and Move, ie the value will be:

```
00000011
```

by bitwise and with move we have:

```
00000011  -->Copy | Move
00000010  -->Move
======== &
00000010 === Move
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suppose :**

`DragDropEffects.Move` has 1 value.
`e.AllowedEffect` has 0 value.

It will do bitwise AND **(1 & 0 = 0)** of the 2 hence the result will be 0 currently:

`DragDropEffects.Move & e.AllowedEffect` will be 0 in this case.

Consider this now :

`DragDropEffects.Move` has 1 value.
`e.AllowedEffect` has 1 value.

in that case bitwise AND will return 1 (as **1 & 1 = 1** in bitwise AND) so now the result will be 1.

Bitwise AND will return 0 if one of the bit is 0 which we are doing AND and will return 1 if all are set to 1.

The second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051349/what-is-the-difference-bettween-bitwise-and-and-logical-and) which you linked in your question explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

`DragDropEffects.Move` has one bit set, the second least significant making it the same as the number `2`.

If you `&` something with `2` then if that bit is set you will get `2` and if that bit is not set, you will get `0`.

So `(x & DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move` will be `true` if the flag for `DragDropEffects.Move` is set in `x` and `false` otherwise.

In languages which allow automatic conversion to boolean it's common to use the more concise `x & DragDropEffects.Move`. The lack of concision is a disadvantage with C# not allowing such automatic conversion, but it does make a lot of mistakes just not happen.

Some people prefer the alternative `(x & DragDropEffects.Move) != 0` (and conversely `(x & DragDropEffects.Move) == 0` to test for a flag not being set) which has the advantage of `0` working here no matter what the enum type or what flag is tested. (And potentially a minor advantage in resulting in very slightly smaller CIL if it is turned straight into a `brzero` instruction, but I think it generally doesn't anyway).

Answer (score 0):

DragDropEffects is not just enum, this is a set of flags, so in your example we check whether e.AllowedEffect has set bits for DragDropEffects.Move or not.

Answer (score 0):

hope you understand how bitwise operators work.

if `e.AllowedEffect` is set to `DragDropEffects.Move` then their & will result in either `e.AllowedEffect`or `DragDropEffects.Move` i.e.

```
e.AllowedEffect = 1
DragDropEffects.Move = 1
e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Move = 1
```

from the MSDN example, it rouhhly means:

'if ActiveEffect is set/equal to DragDropEffects.Move then do this...'