# Bitwise AND operation on boolean values in C

Tags: c, boolean-expression, bitwise-and

I have a doubt in usage of Boolean variable in below expression.

```
bool x,y;
x &= y;    // expression 1 [which means x = x & y]
x &&= y;   // expression 2 [which means x = x && y]
```

In above 2 expressions which one is correct and why ? Where x and y both are Boolean and I want to perform x = x && y operation.

Also if I use expression 2 in my C code I get a compilation error saying syntax error.

Doubts:
Can we use bitwise AND on boolean variables ?
Why I am getting compilation error in second expression?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051349/what-is-the-difference-bettween-bitwise-and-and-logical-and

Comment: @Chris, Diff between logical and bitwise AND is understood but my question here is can we use bitwise AND on boolean variables? and why I get a compilation error in expression 2.

Comment: Yes you can use them on boolean variables, depending on the language I suppose. It works in Java for me. The explanation for your second question is in the answer below.

Comment: Because there is no `&&=` operator in C.

Comment: `_Bool` (typedef'd to `bool`) is one of the standard unsigned integer types, so it's legal to use the bitwise `&` and `|` operators with `bool` operands.  C does not define a `&&=` operator, which is why you get the compile error.

Comment: after some googling found this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-assignment-operator       The & operator performs a bitwise logical AND operation on integral operands and logical AND on bool operands.

Comment: @JohnBode It's a thin line here. Some might take just two non-zero integers, and knowing they are evaluating to truth, consider them equivalent to `true`, and then perform the bitwise operation. But suddenly discover that `1 & 2` evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @Viki C# and C are *very different* languages. So using docs of one as a reference for the other might lead to a very wrong conclusions.

Comment: Agreed @EugeneSh. But i guess similar thing applies to C for this question.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yeah, there's that.  I should have clarified that "legal" simply means "not a constraint violation".

Comment: @Eugene Sh. you are shocking me. Someone with you reputation should know the distinction between logical & bitwise operators. so everything not zero is true in C and zero false. 1 & 2 is a bitwise operation (0b01 & 0b10) so the result is 0. 1 && 2 is a logical operation and the result is 1 (true). Result of the logical operation is always 1 or 0. One of the tricks is using of !! operators to get 1 if not zero or zero id zero.

Comment: @PeterJ Reread and understand my comment.

Comment: @PeterJ: Eugene is pointing out that `&&` and `&` are not interchangeable, and that you shouldn't use `&` for logical operations,

Comment: "`which i guess`" - A simple search for "c operators" and a bit of reading to be sure was too much? That way you would also have found there is no `&&=` operator (as there is no `||=` operator either, just in case the next question pops up). Post3ers are required to show their research. We are not a tutoring site for such basic stuff found in every C book.

Comment: @Olaf agreed I did bit of research but totally missed that &&= operator doesnt exists in C.