# What does |= signify in C++?

Tags: c++, caffe

I was going through the source code of Intel's deep learning framework Caffe, when I came across `|=`. I've never seen that before in any code. In fact, I found it twice in the code. [Line 188](https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp#L188):

```
need_backward |= blob_need_backward_[blob_id];
```

and [line 254](https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp#L254):

```
need_backward |= param_need_backward;
```

I realize that they both are housed in a for loop which might signify some kind of relation. I'm just assuming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about adequately documented basic syntax.

Comment: [Scroll down here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm) "bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator"

Comment: `|` is a bitwise OR operator. `X op= Y` is a shorthand for `X = X op Y`. Thus, `|=` performs bitwise OR of the two arguments and assigns the result to the first one.

Comment: I also don't want to discourage you, or actually: I want to -- I wonder whether you should start with something simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Thats the 'bitwise OR assignment' compund assignment operator.

```
x |= y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = x | y;
```

There are a number of similar operators: +=, -=, *=, etc.

See: [operator_assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)

Answer (score 2):

`|=` is a compound assignment.

`<var> |= <expr>` means `<var> = <var> | <expr>`

It is the bitwise `OR` equivalent of `+=` for incrementing. You can do this with most mathematical operators in C++.

`|` is [bitwise `OR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154132/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-and-conditional-and-or-in-c), so you're reassigning a variable to its `OR`'d result.

Answer (score 1):

it is shorthand for

```
need_backward = need_backward | param_need_backward;
```

you are performing **bitwise or operation**

Comment: I think it differs from the long version in that the left hand side is only evaluated once. Imagine a function call with a side effect, returning a reference.