# What does | (pipe) mean in c#?

Tags: c#

Just wondering what the pipe means in this? ive never seen it before:

```
FileSystemAccessRule fullPermissions = new FileSystemAccessRule(
             "Network Service",
             FileSystemRights.FullControl | FileSystemRights.Modify,
             AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators

Comment: @Martinho - The OP says "the pipe", so yes - he/she means the "|". The rest is there for context.

Comment: yes I did say pipe in my question? I mean the pipe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is normally a [bitwise or operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  In this context, it's used on an enum with the [flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) set.

Comment: I dont get it so which value are you actually passing to the second parameter?

Comment: You are a passing a combination of `FileSystemRights.FullControl` and `FileSystemRights.Modify`.

Comment: Both of them.  Think of them as binary: `FileSystemRights.FullControl = 00000001` and `FileSystemRights.Modify = 00000010`  The OR combines these fields into `00000011` and passes that value to the method. (These values may not be accurate)

Comment: Both (FullControl OR FileSystemRights.Modify)

Comment: which one though? How can it be a logical OR there is no condition these are hardcoded values in the .net framework....

Comment: why would I do this? im still confused

Comment: Its a Bitwise OR, not a logical OR.

Comment: I this case it doesn't make much sense because the FullControl would logically override the Modify flag.  Consider this though:  you want to be able to specifiy read and write permissions.  If that enum had a `Read` and a `Write` value, then you would specify both values using the bitwise OR (|).

Comment: @Kyle: FYI MSDN calls it a logical operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Pete2k:  There doesn't need to be a condition.  `|` is an operator that can be applied to flag enums.  The result will be a new value of the same type that isn't necessarily equal to any of the individual enum values, but rather a combination of multiple values.

Comment: @recursive how would this work in practice? How do I allow eunms in this fasion to be put in the method declaration and then do anything useful with them?

Comment: @Pete2K You can read is as "A and B" (i.e., a UNION) but that's not the same as `(A && B)`. The bit is set to `1` if A OR B is `1`.

Comment: then in that case its a useless statement. The method wants an enum and we are passing it the value of the logical union of A and B. Not sure how this actually works or is meant to do!?

Comment: @Pete2k: It uses the flag attribute.  I put a link in my answer.  Go read about the flag attribute.

Answer (score 18):

For an enum marked with the [Flags] attribute the vertical bar means 'and', i.e. add the given values together.

Edit: This is a bitwise 'or' (though semantically 'and'), e.g.:

```
[Flags]
public enum Days
{
     Sunday    = 0x01,
     Monday    = 0x02,
     Tuesday   = 0x04,
     Wednesday = 0x08,
     Thursday  = 0x10,
     Friday    = 0x20,
     Saturday  =  0x40,
}

// equals = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 62
Days weekdays = Days.Monday | Days.Tuesday | Days.Wednesday | Days.Thursday | Days.Friday;
```

It's a bitwise-OR but semantically you think of it as an AND!

Comment: Though semantically correct using the word "and" to describe an "or" to me is extraordinarily confusing.

Comment: it is, why would I use this to pass into a method?

Comment: @Pete2k, if you wanted to use multiple values of a flag-type enum, i.e. in the example in your question, I want FullControl AND Modify.

Comment: For those who share confusion with @Joe: with bitwise-OR logic gates, the computer's perspective is :
"I want to know if value `x` is true **or** value `y` is true **or** value `z` is true. If it is, I'll evaluate the whole condition to true."

When doing things like setting a type attribute to allow multiple types through, we would say `[FooTypeCheck( x | y | z)]`. The computer sees three conditions and only needs one to be valid. The human sees 
"This member allows type `x` **and** `y` **and** `z`." 
Thus "semantic and".

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise OR of two values, presumably it creates a FileAccessRule with both FullAccess and Modify permissions set.

Comment: You mean BITWISE or.  Logical OR is ||

Comment: +1 FileSystemRights would be an enum that is representative of a bitmask; aka one element of the enum is 1, the next is 2, the next 4, etc. So you can write 1101 as 3 enum values masked.

Comment: @Joe:  The c# spec actually calls it a logical operator, even though it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [binary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Binary | operators are predefined for
>   the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, | computes the bitwise
>   OR of its operands. For bool operands,
>   | computes the logical OR of its
>   operands; that is, the result is false
>   if and only if both its operands are
>   false.

Comment: `+`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&&`, `||`, and usually `-` are all binary operators.  In that context, "binary operator" just means it takes two arguments, one on the left and one on the right.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean this: `FileSystemRights.FullControl | FileSystemRights.Modify`

This FileSystemRights, is an enum with FullControl and Modify having their own numeric values.

So if FullControl = 1 and Modify = 2,

```
FileSystemRights.FullControl | FileSystemRights.Modify = 3.  
00000001 | 00000010 = 00000011.
```

Each bit is a "flag" for the method.  The input checks to see which "flag" is set and what to do.

So in this example, position 1 (the digit all the way on the right in this case) is FullControl, and position 2 is Modify.  The method looks at each of the positions, and changes it behavior.  Using flags is a way of passing in multiple parameters of behaviors without having to create a parameter for each possiblity (e.g. bool allowFullControl, bool allowModify) etc.

[Bitwise Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's a boolean or. FullControl and Modify represent bits in a mask. For example 0001 and 0101. If you would combine those via pipe, you would get 0101.