# What does a single | or & mean?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the diffference between the | and || or operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators)
>   [What does | (pipe) mean in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705262/what-does-pipe-mean-in-c)

I have some code that was written by another developer in the office, who isn't in at the moment. I have some work to do on his code, but I have not coma across this before. I tried searching on here, but it strips my | out of the search line. I also don't know what the name for that symbol is, so couldn't search for it like that.

```
this.Action.Values[key] = (int)this.Action.Values[key] | 1;
```

My question is what does the single or do in this instance?

Comment: bitwise 'or' and bitwise 'and' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate post, as I mentioned in the question the search box on this site strips out the | symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bar (or pipe), `|` is a bit-wise `OR` operator, and the easiest way of explaining it is that it allows us to combine flags.  Consider:

```
[Flags]
public enum WindowFlags
{
    None = 0, 
    Movable = 1,
    HasCloseBox = 2,
    HasMinimizeBox = 4,
    HasMaximizeBox = 8
}
```

Using the bitwise-OR operator, we can combine flags, thusly:

```
WindowFlags flags = WindowFlags .Movable | WindowFlags .HasCloseBox | WindowFlags .HasMinimizeBox;
```

We can "test" for a given flag, using:

```
bool isMovable = (flags & WindowFlags .Movable);
```

Removing flags is a bit more of a strain on the eyeballs:

```
flags &= ~WindowFlags.HasCloseBox;  // remove HasCloseBox flag
```

Answer (score 4):

These are bitwise operations.

Example

```
  011000101
| 100100100
-----------
= 111100101


  011000101
& 100100100
-----------
= 000000100
```

Answer (score 1):

This operator mean just `OR`.

> Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool
>   operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the
>   result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

See all the operators [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in c#

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

& = bitwise AND
| = bitwise OR

Answer (score 1):

> |  -->   logical/bitwise OR
>
> & -- > logical/bitwise AND

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's a bitwise operator. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe "|" is a bitwise or operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A single | is bitwise OR operator