# difference between logical operators & and |

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logical-operators

| is an OR and & is AND.

I have the following code and they works OPPOSITE.

```
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int c = -1;
            if ((a | b | c) == 0) 
            {
                textBox8.Text = "everything 0"; 
            }
            else
            {
                textBox8.Text = "something is not a 0"; // <- code goes here
            }            
            if ((a & b & c) == 0)
            {
                textBox9.Text = "everything 0";  // <- code goes here            
            }
            else
            {
                textBox9.Text = "something is not a 0";               
            }
```

why i have this result?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Afv6.jpg

Comment: because `(a & b & c) == 0` doesn't mean "everything 0" but "there is no common bits setted"

Comment: Are you confusing _bitwise_ or `|` with _logical_ or `||`?

Comment: [What is the difference between the | and || or operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-or-operators)

Comment: `a == 0 && b == 0 && c ==0`  ... you have to use && for `and` and || for Or

Comment: @Jawad Actually if you do it that way you can use `&` since you're now dealing with `bool` values and that will behave as a logical and.  However the `&&` will short circuit and stop comparing at the first `false` value. One reason to always use `||` and `&&` for logical operations is that you can not accidently apply them to anything that isn't `bool`.

Comment: related [What does a single | or & mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736751/what-does-a-single-or-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a | b | c) == 0` does NOT mean "a is zero or b is zero or c is zero". For that you'd need `(a==0 | b==0 | c==0)` (you could also use `||`, which stops evaluating after one operand is true).

With numeric operands, `|` is a [bitwise "OR" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-), which you can read about separately. `||` is not valid for anything other than boolean operands, so it can be useful to be in the habit of using `||` unless you *explicitly* don't want short-circuiting. That way you don't ever accidentally use it as a bitwise operator when you *indented* to use it as a logical operator. (it would have been a compiler error in this instance, for example).