# What is the "|=" operator in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, nullreferenceexception, enum-flags

In researching the cause of a bug, I came across this line of code:

```
Status |= (int)states.Reading;
```

What is the "|=" operator in C#?

"Status" is defined thusly:

```
public static int Status
```

...with an accessor and mutator (or "getter" and "setter"), while "states" is defined this way:

```
[Flags]
public  enum states
```

Comment: But the whole line isn't commented out... ?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right - that is obvious here, but not in the editor (because of color syntax highlighting (the lack thereof in my VS2003 setup)). So, I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Close, but no dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705262/what-does-pipe-mean-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the "bitwise logical OR" operator, as defined [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

`x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x | y`

Also, if you want to learn more about the "|" operator itself, you can do so [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

While using the enumerators if you have specified [Flags] attribute on top of an "enum" member, this enables the user to select more than one enumerators in a single go.
What I mean is this:-

if this is your enumerator:-

```
[Serializable, DataContract(Namespace = "Company.Domain.LOB.Handler")]
[Flags]
public enum BankItemStatus
{
    [EnumMember]
    UnBatched,
    [EnumMember]
    Batched,
    [EnumMember]
    Sent,
    [EnumMember]
    ReplyReceived,
    [EnumMember]
    Closed
}
```

Now if you use the Enum like this:-

```
BankItemStatus bankItemStatus = BankItemStatus.UnBatched;
BankItemStatus bankItemStatus = BankItemStatus.Sent;
```

The final value preserved by bankItemStatus would be BankItemStatus.Sent.
You can check it like this:-

```
if(bankItemStatus.UnBatched==BankItemStatus.UnBatched) //FALSE
if(bankItemStatus.Sent==BankItemStatus.Sent) //TRUE
```

Now if you do it like this:-

```
BankItemStatus bankItemStatus = BankItemStatus.UnBatched;
bankItemStatus |= bankItemStatus.Sent
```

You will see that bankItemStatus now has both the enum members.
You can check it like this:-

```
if(bankItemStatus.UnBatched==BankItemStatus.UnBatched) //TRUE
if(bankItemStatus.Sent==BankItemStatus.Sent) //TRUE
```

Hope that helps in understanding the use of |= operator in C# (in context of Enumerators).

Comment: Great answer, thanks; I once changed an answer I had marked as correct to another cat who provided a more detailed answer, and the original awarded answerer wept inconsolably, so I will leave the accepted answer as-is, although this one is great. BTW, "BatchItemStatus" should be "BankItemStatus" in the enum definition.