# Compare a string to multiple strings

Tags: c#

Is there a way to compare two strings to another string at once?

Example:

```
string1 == string2 && string3;
```

(I know this isn't the way, just a representation of what I mean)

Comment: `&` or `&&`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301

Comment: `&` looks like the VB.NET [concatenation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx). Is that intended?

Comment: `string1 == string2 == string3` ??

Comment: @Bolu, wow...... remove it.

Comment: @Bolu `(string1 == string2)` is bool then `(bool) == string3`.

Comment: the incredible is that @Bolu comment still got 2 upvotes...

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw just comparing the contents, not comparing two concatenated strings.

Comment: or `string1 == (string2||string3)` ??

Comment: Bolu your codes are doesn't even compile. You are lucky because there is no downvote on comments.

Comment: @Bolu - which would work if all three were `bool`

Comment: @Selman22, I was suggesting how should these be represented in just one sentence..... if it exists.....

Comment: @Callum, just for my peace of mind, you know you can use `string1 == string2 && string1 == string3;` and you are just looking for a short line, right?

Comment: @Bolu yes, I was just trying to find out if there was an easier way as it is a line I have to write quite a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, no, there is no way to do this that resembles the way you asked to do it.

However, if the strings to compare with are in a collection of some kind, you can do this:

```
 if (stringCollection.All(s => s == string1) )
```

Comment: That or `if (stringCollection.Any(s => s == string1) )`. All returns true if all elements match. Any returns true if one or more elements match

Comment: Sorry just want to clarify, is that comparing all the strings in the collection to one another, or just one to all the others?

Comment: @Callum It compares one to all the others... but since you used an _AND_ operator, it should match what your pseudocode was looking for here.

Comment: @Callum: the portion `(s => s... ` refers to your other strings, string2 and 3 which should be in a collection

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah that's what I was after, but since they aren't already in a collection it will probably be easier to just do two comparisons. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Besides Linq's All method, you can do also with [List methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like [TrueForAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    string searchString = "hi";
    var listStrings = new List<string>() { "hi", "there" };
    bool allOfThem = listStrings.TrueForAll(x => x == searchString);
    bool atLeastOne = listStrings.Contains(searchString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with putting your values into a collection or list, you could do an extension method like this:

```
static class extensions
{
    private static bool InSet(this string s, params string[] p )
    {
        return p.Contains(s);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to test if a string matches a value in a set you can do this:

```
if (String1.InSet(String2, String3))
{
    // do something.
}
```

Comment: I would like to add, that this solution works with any number of parameters.