# C# is there a equivalent short circuit for |=

Tags: c#

I am setting the visibility of a button and I have code like

```
    btnReset.Visible |= newCondition();
```

What I noticed is `|=` is not short circuited, and `||=` does not exist.  Granted I can rewrite the statement as

```
    btnReset.Visible = btnReset.Visible || newCondition();
```

**But I was just curious if there was a short hand short circuit operator?**

Below is test code to verify that `|=` is not short circuit

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        bool firstValue = true;

        // Short Circuit 
        bool secondValue = firstValue || CallThisFunction();

        // Full Evaluation 
        bool thirdValue = firstValue | CallThisFunction();

        // Full Evaluation 
        secondValue |= CallThisFunction();
    }

    private static bool CallThisFunction()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Well you can't short-circuit |= because it's a bitwise operator. Just because the LHS is non-zero doesn't mean the value of the RHS wouldn't have an effect on the result.

Comment: Sure but is there a equivalent to ||=

Comment: Nope, you have to use the longhand.

Comment: To extend upon to @MatthewWatson , the bitwise operator works with booleans properly because of binary representation of true and false. In VB.NET these are also often confused, `And` isnt the same as `AndAlso` , its the same here.

Comment: I don't think it is a dupe because the question you reference is "Why" doesn't it... I am asking "Is there another way"

Comment: [Difference betwen `|` and `||`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35301/1997232).

Comment: Again I do know the difference, as you see from the code example, the question was not "What" or "Why" but "Is this function available"