# Bitwise Or of null check in C#

Tags: c#, null, iequalitycomparer, bitwise-or

I was going through the IEqualityComparer Example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)
I don't understand the need for the second condition with Bitwise Or

```
if (b2 == null && b1 == null)
   return true;
else if (b1 == null | b2 == null)
   return false;
```

Why is there a need for such a condition?

Comment: Hovering the mouse over the pipe operator, i see a tooltip which reads "bool bool.operator|(bool left, bool right);` It appears that `bool` overloads that operator to act as a boolean or. Testing confirms that it compiles and for `bool a, b;`, `a | b` evaluates identically to `a || b`. Bonus trivia: `a ^ b` evaluates as boolean XOR, and `a & b` as boolean AND.

Comment: Probably a  mistake, inform Microsoft. Should be ||.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I doubt that's an error, it's rarely used but its a performance boost when used properly. Seems to be the case here.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich in the case of two boolean values, wouldn't | produce the same results as ||? (although evaluated a little differently since || can short circuit, although I suspect | is faster in this case)

Comment: @EdPlunkett `|` and `||` do not evaluate identically. If you use `||`, `b` will not be evaluated. If you use `|`, then `b` will be evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the | and || or operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-or-operators)

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Thank you, i stand corrected

Comment: The answer lies here https://ericlippert.com/2015/11/02/when-would-you-use-on-a-bool/

Comment: @hatchet I just did a not scientific test and `||` was consistently faster than `|`.

Comment: @hatchet That's the accurate explanation. I ran a basic test to verify it. I hope someone upvotes your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition returns true (equal) if both are null.

When you get to the second condition it's already determined that they aren't both null (or else the first condition would have been true.)

So in the second condition if either one is null then that means that only one of them is null. If one is null and the other isn't then they aren't equal.