# What is this "|" (pipe) means in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2

In the context of Security Cryptography X509Certificates, I've came across this in one of the projects code.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
```

What is this "|" pipe means here?

Comment: Before all the "read the docs" answers come in, in layman terms it effectively means open the store with both those options enabled. Have a look up on how Flags & Bitwise operators work.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/340760

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301/340760

Comment: If you are going to program in C# RTFM, this is the most basic, it was in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bitwise OR operator. In this case, it is used to combine flags. Meaning you open the store in Read/Write mode and only if it already exists. There's more explanation on bitwise operators on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/or-operator).

Answer (score 0):

The binary Or operator is arithmetic OR between two integers, and with a Flags `enum`, combines the two flags into one value.

[MSDN Flags Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx)