# Check for specific characters in string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have a group of unwanted characters `& "  > < { } ( )` and I want to validate that a given string does not contains those  characters, for now I wrote function like:

```
bool IsStringValid(string s){
  if(s.Contains("&")| s.Contains(">")...)
    return false;
return true;
}
```

How can I write it more elegant? for example in regex?

Comment: You could create a `HashSet<char>` of the undesired characters then just do `return s.All(c => !undesired.Contains(c));`

Comment: @juharr nice idea

Comment: Btw you should use ||, not | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-or-operators

Comment: @AntonínLejsek You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isValid =  !Regex.IsMatch(input, "[&\"><{}()]+");
```

But however I recommand you do it without regex:

```
bool isValid = !"&\"><{}()".Any(c=> input.Contains(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is always your friend.

```
Regex validationRegex = new Regex(@"^[^&""><{}\(\)]*$");

bool IsStringValid(string s) => validationRegex.IsMatch(s);
```