# Why is my code not returning the sum using while loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop, sum

I'm trying to find the sum from (1 to n) or given number. 
using this code:

```
        int n;
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        Console.Write("Please enter the sum limit number: ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //around here is where code freezes and nothing else happens 
        while(counter <=  n)
        {
            counter = +1;
            sum = sum + counter;
        }

        Console.Write("The sum from 1 - " + n + " =" + sum);
```

I know I can use:

```
        int n;
        int counter = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        Console.Write("Please enter the sum limit number: ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, n);

        Console.Write("The sum from 1 - " + n + " =" + sum.Sum());
```

but my next challenge is to only add the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5, so I'm planning on doing:

```
        if (sum % 3 == 0 | sum % 5 == 0)
        { 
         total = total + sum;
        }
```

What is wrong with my method? Also, alternative ways to do this are more than appreciated!

Comment: You need to increment `counter` - try `counter += 1;` instead of `counter = +1;`

Comment: Note that [`|` is not the same operation as `||` (short-circuiting boolean or)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-or-operators)

Comment: @John `|` can a boolean OR as well, it just does not short-circuit (both sides are evaluated even of the first is true).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I got a value not what I was expecting but getting somewhere. I just looked up +=  operator and to my understanding it's equals to a+=b == a = a+b, but isn't the operation counter = +1; increasing counter + 1 as well? also if my understanding is right could I also do sum += counter;? thank you for you help!

Comment: @euw0o83hf Thank you so much for your help, I got it working now and managed to make it shorted as well!

Comment: For anything involving math - in particular indexes - you should be using a for loop. Sometimes foreach. While does not really fit. It makes you intention clear on a glance. Personally while is my least used loop. I tend towards using for, foreach and do...while a few orders of magnitude more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get out of while loop, condition needs to satisfy.First you need increment counter present in while loop.

To increment counter variable either you can try `counter++/++counter` i.e. post/pre increment operator or you can do `counter += 1/ counter = counter + 1.`

Something similar to

```
    //around here is where code freezes and nothing else happens 
    while(counter <=  n)
    {
        counter += 1;  // not counter=+1;
        sum = sum + counter;
    }
```

Reference: [Increment decrement in C#](https://www.dotnetperls.com/increment)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increment the counter you should either use

`counter = counter + 1;`

or

`counter++;`

or

`counter += 1;`

Comment: Or `++counter;` :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't expect my question to be answered so quick or at all! you guys are the best!