# Filter data based on enum value

Tags: c#

I have a model that looks like this

```
     [Column("StatusId")]
     public FileStatus Status { get; set; }

     public int Id { get; set; }
```

I also have an enum that looks like this.

```
     public enum FileStatus
        {
            MessageInProgress,
            MessageDone,
            NoMessage
        }
```

I am pulling data from my repository to populate data variable below

```
    IEnumerable<MyFile> data = await _fileDataRepository.GetAllData(Id);
```

I want to filter data such that I will remove any record that has a status
of MessageDone or NoMessage.

This code does not work for me.

```
    data.where( x => x.Status != "MessageDone" | x.Status != "NoMessage")
```

How do I achieve the filtering?

Comment: dont use strings. use `&&` instead of `|`. don't capture as an `IEnumerable` as it will pull things too much.

Comment: Instead of using a string why not just use the enum itself? `x.Status != FileStatus.MessageDone`. Also you should have `&&` instead of `|` for the comparison operator.

Comment: I'd add an overload `GetAllData(Id, status)` where `status` is one of `FileStatus` values and do the filter in the DAL.

Answer (score 2):

2 things you need to change:

1. `FileStatus` is `enum` and you use it as a `string`.
2. You used `|` which is "boolean logical or" and you should use "Conditional logical and" `&&` (You can use `&` but most of the times is better to use conditional operator because of the laziness ([For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35314/7122901))).

You should change it to:

`data.where(x => x.Status != FileStatus.MessageDone && x.Status != FileStatus.NoMessage)`

Or more simple:

`data.where(x => x.Status == FileStatus.MessageInProgress)`

Comment: Good answer and explanation with solution; the last code snippet is best.

Comment: The reason why I used Or | is that  I want to filter the data when the enum is MessageDone, or NoMessage. Both of this message cannot exist at the same time. It is just one at a time that can exist in the table

Comment: from MSDN: The result of x | y is true if either x or y evaluates to true. As you mentioned, In your case `x.Status` can't be both, so one of the operands will be always true.

Comment: The filtering is not working. I am still getting a record back that has a status of MessageDone and it should not come back

Comment: Maybe it changes after the filter? You can put a breakpoint on the setter of `Status` and check it.